# Как решить ошибку npm ERR?

Tags: npm

код ошибки

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-8e864196fa38aa96.lock
npm ERR! errno -4075
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, open 'C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-8e864196fa38aa96.lock'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-8e864196fa38aa96.lock
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-23T18_18_07_018Z-debug.log
```

пробовал использовать следующие решения
презагрузил пк

```
npm install uglify-js --save-dev
npm cache clean --force
npm i npm -g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось пересозданием проекта. При чем все файлы создание ,в ошибочном проекте, перенес в новый и все норм.